# How do I remove Growl notifications for one contact only in Adium?

Tags: twitter, jabber, growl, adium

I've written a little script to pipe Twitter in and out of Jabber. I'm using Adium on OS X to get these messages: and I have it so when Adium is in the background, it pops up a Jabber notification. I like this behaviour, but I don't want it to happen on the account I'm using to send the tweets into Jabber - because, you know, having a Growl notification pop up every time someone tweets is *quite annoying*.

In Adium, I've found out how you can set specific notifications for a contact, but it only seems to have the ability to add *extra* notifications for a particular user, rather than the ability to remove notifications. I could make my defaults set to be the least noisy I ever want, but then I'd have to replicate the settings I want for normal people for each person (possibly by hand) when all I really want is for my Twitter bot to be quiet while letting human contacts use the default set of notification preferences?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed [here](http://hg.adium.im/adium/rev/a71c719e9271).

The new feature can be found in the Adium 1.5 nightly builds [here](http://nightly.adium.im).

Those nightlies might be pretty unstable.  I don't know if they work yet, I'm just now trying one out for the same reason. So far so good.